# How does mktexmf find fonts on mac?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I installed a new font using Font Book on my mac.  But when I try using fontspec, I get an error that says "font-not-found".  It seems that the name that appears in the Font Book application is not the same as the files for the font that were installed, but I tried different names and it still doesn't seem to be able to load.  When I select "show in finder" in Font Book, it shows me that the files are stored in ~/Library/Fonts.  Any ideas on why fontspec is having issues?

The font is called "Fontin," and I downloaded it from http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html  There seem to be several files that correspond to Fontin in ~/Library/Fonts, which include Fontin_19.suit, FontiReg, FontiSmaCap.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} 

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What's the name of the font and of the file that contains the font? With which instruction do you try to load the font?

Comment: The error you see regarding `mktexmf` is misleading. XeTeX first tries system fonts; if it doesn't find the requested one, the standard mechanism based on building the font from Metafont sources pops in. In your case it just means XeTeX is not able to find the system font. What's its name?

Comment: @egreg I added a few details to the question.

Comment: You should look at the font name corresponding to `FontiSmaCap` by getting info from Font Book.

Comment: @egreg Where does that name appear?  The only thing I see in Font Book is Fontin, and under that there is one called Fontin SmallCaps.

Comment: @asperanz Sorry, I don't have the font.

Comment: @Mico I added the font name and the file where it is located.